# iOS How to Save Image from UIView without lose quality of image

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uiview, uiimage

I have images that are drawn in a UIView, then lines are drawn on them. How can I can save the image with the painted lines to a UIImage object with the same image size it began with, and without losing any image quality?

ie. I have an image of size (3264, 2448).
That is drawn in a UIView (size 375, 281) that AspectFit with the image,
then a line is painted on the image.  Finally, how can I save the image from the UIView to a UIImage with size (3264, 2448) without losing image quality?

If this is not the best approach, please recommend a better way to accomplish this.

```
class DrawingView: UIImageView {

    private var pts = [CGPoint](count: 5, repeatedValue: CGPoint())
    private var ctr: uint!

    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 4.0
    var lineColor: UIColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, image: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.image = image
        beginDrawingView()
   }

   private func beginDrawingView() {
        userInteractionEnabled = true
   }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        ctr = 0
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            pts[0] = touch.locationInView(self) as CGPoint
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            let p: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
            ctr = ctr + 1
            pts[Int(ctr)] = p
            if ctr == 4 {
                pts[3] = CGPointMake((pts[2].x + pts[4].x)/2.0, (pts[2].y + pts[4].y)/2.0); 

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
                let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

                image!.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height))
                CGContextSaveGState(context)

                CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true)
                CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth)
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor)

                let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
                CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, pts[0].x, pts[0].y)
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, pts[1].x, pts[1].y, pts[2].x, pts[2].y, pts[3].x, pts[3].y)

                CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)

                CGContextAddPath(context, path)
                CGContextStrokePath(context)


                image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                CGContextRestoreGState(context)
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                pts[0] = pts[3]
                pts[1] = pts[4]
                ctr = 1
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the image source? why dont you just save the source?

Comment: You can save the image link in string or try saving the image data in **NSData** format.

Comment: Can you please share your code here so getting more idea what you are doing while saving the image.

Comment: @u.gen i'm wish image is background and can drawing line over on it, then save image background and drawing line to last image. So i can't save source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but if you already have a `UIImage` object, you can just save it as a `Base64String`. Here is some code that I use for this (you'll notice that I also perform compression on any JPG images because I'm saving the string to a database, but of course you wouldn't need that component since you don't want to lose image quality):

```
//Convert the image to Base64String with optional JPG compression
//
-(NSString*)convertImageToBase64String:(UIImage*)image withImageType:(NSString*)imageType
{
    NSData* data;
    if ([imageType isEqualToString:@"PNG"]) {
        data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    } else if ([imageType isEqualToString:@"JPG"] || [imageType isEqualToString:@"JPEG"]) {
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);
    }

return [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

If you don't have the UIImage object yet, though, you could get it by taking a screenshot like this:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

I haven't tested the last block of code, but I suspect it will give you a screenshot of the ENTIRE screen, so you would need to the `view.bounds.size` component to get the exact area you are looking for.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but i test last block it draw my view as small area and remain space is lightgray color in my image. ( i see from break point )

Comment: Like I said, I haven't tested the second code block; you may need to tweak the view.bounds.size or other options for this code to work.